# Using Mercurial, how can I measure individual contributions?

Tags: mercurial, metrics, measurement

My team is using Mercurial, and I would like to know the relative contributions by each team member. I know that we cannot measure productivity by lines of code, but I would like to see if each person at least contributed *something*, even if it was overwritten by others later. So, I don't just want to see who is responsible for the current version (a la Mercurial annotate), but to do this recursively through all revisions, ideally with output that can be easily visualized or dumped into a spreadsheet.

Any tips?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's an extension exactly for this, named `churn`, it is bundled with Mercurial, but not automatically enabled. You can find more information here: [ChurnExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChurnExtension).

In your mercurial.ini file, to the `[extensions]` section, add the following:

```
[extensions]
churn=
```

Then to look at the churn of your repository, just do:

```
hg churn
```

This will output something like this (this is for the [Noda-Time project](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/)):

```
[C:\Dev\VS.NET\Noda-Time-docs] :hg churn
skeet@pobox.com              296444 *************************************************************************************************************
james.keesey@gmail.com       203877 ***************************************************************************
James Keesey                  80466 ******************************
dmitry.bulavin@gmail.com      25552 *********
Dmitry Bullavin               17657 ******
martinho.fernandes@gmail.com  16325 ******
Dmitry Bulavin                 4273 **
james.keesey                   2650 *
matt.scharley                   768
configurator                    450
lasse@vkarlsen.no                64
TeamCity@Nordrassil               2
```

Comment: It's an interesting thing that it lists some users twice, however, they may have changed their names. +1 anyway, nice to know

Comment: It lists per unique name, and the names are all unique. You can, however, provide an alias file that renames some names, specifically to combat this issue.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Churn does the job, but note that it if a user moves files a lot, he will have huge amounts of changed lines. I just did a test, here are the results:

```
C:\Projects\personal\test>hg churn
darius.damalakas@gmail.com     10 *****************************************

C:\Projects\personal\test>hg mv a.a b.b
moving a.a to b.b

C:\Projects\personal\test>hg commit -m "moving 10 lines to another location"
b.b
committed changeset 1:c54200557152

C:\Projects\personal\test>hg churn
darius.damalakas@gmail.com     30 *****************************************
```

Note that I have only created 10 lines, but for moving a file I got 20 line changes. That does not convey a good picture.

Comment: This is probably better suited as a short comment to Lasse's answer.